# How can I rewrite alternative $setTimeout function such that it is easier to read?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Initially, in AngularJS, I had a function I wanted to periodically call. So, I used the `$setInterval` function to do this. However, upon doing so, I noticed that even when leaving the page, the function continued to run and completely filling my console with errors until I navigated back onto the page associated with the function. I replaced my `$setInterval` function, with a solution I found [here](http://www.thecodeship.com/web-development/alternative-to-javascript-evil-setinterval/). This guy writes a whole new version of `$setInterval`. It appears as:

```
function interval(func, wait, times) {
    var interv = function(w,t){
        return function(){
            if(typeof t === "undefined" || t--> 0){
                setTimeout(interv, w);
                try{
                    func.call(null);
                }catch(e){
                    t = 0;
                    throw e.toString();
                }
            }
        };
    }(wait,times);
    setTimeout(interv,wait);
};
```

And I basically call my function as:

```
interval($scope.setValue, 100);
```

This function works exactly as I wish, and our prior problem has been solve. But now, readability has become an issue, and I have wondering if there was a way to rewrite this function such that it is easier to read (possible has less code) but functions in the same manner?

Comment: Yes, the function creating the `interv` function is completely unnecessary. As is the `;` after the function declaration (`;` terminate statements, not declarations).

Comment: Did you *retype* this in order to put it in the question, rather than copy and paste? Right now, it has an undefined identifier (`func`), as the parameter is `fund`.

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I guess the autocorrect changed it without me noticing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a take on it, with comments for clarity which make it seem longer although it isn't:

```
function interval(func, wait, times) {
    // Set `t` to either Infinity or the number of times we're supposed to repeat
    var t = typeof times == "undefined" ? Infinity : times;

    // The tick function we call
    function tick() {
        // Set up the next iteration if appropriate
        // Note that --Infinity is Infinity, so it will never stop in that case
        if (--t > 0) {
            setTimeout(tick, wait);
        }

        // Call the function, canceling further repeats if it throws an exception
        try {
            func.call(null); // Or just func() seems like it should be good enough, really
        } catch(e) {
            t = 0;
            throw e;
        }
    }

    // Start the process
    setTimeout(tick, wait);
}
```

That preserves a couple of behaviors of the current function which are different from the standard `setInterval` (I can't speak for Angular's):

- It stops trying to call the function if the function fails once
- It has a feature letting you specify the max number of times to call the function (which seems handy)